# $AB - BA = \lambda B$ has a nontrivial solution, iff $\lambda = \lambda_i - \lambda_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

I have the following question in hand.

If $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ are the eigenvalues of a given matrix $A \in M_n$, then prove that the matrix equation $AB - BA = \lambda B$ has a nontrivial solution $B \neq 0 \in M_n$, if and only if $\lambda = \lambda_i - \lambda_j$ for some $i,j$.

Comment: In the suggested solution of this link, an assumption is that $E$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: No, it says that we may assume - without loss of generality- that $E$ is diagonal. If $E$ is not diagonalizable, we can use Jordan blocks.

Comment: Seeing that n lambdas are given, it is fair to assume that the matrix is supposed to be diagonalizable. Otherwise one needs to assume an algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the operator $B\mapsto [A,B]$. What are its eigenvalues?

Comment: I think $AB$ and $BA$ should have the same spectrum (or same characteristic polynomial). I guess only ordering of the eigenvalues is different.

Comment: @user550103 The question is a different one here, though. Not about the eigenvalues of the commutator, but of the map that takes the bracket with $A$.

Comment: I must admit that I feel I have knowledge gap here :(. I am not familiar with this mapping as such. If you can give some reference, then I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: Would you mind to review my below attempt? I have tried bit differently (utilizing "the toolset" I have so far).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt. Does this make sense to you experts?

If we vectorize such that
\begin{align}
AB - BA &=  \lambda B \\
&\Downarrow \\
\mbox{vec}\left(AB - BA \right) &= \mbox{vec}(\lambda B) \\
\mbox{vec}\left(ABI - IBA \right) &= \mbox{vec}(\lambda B) \\
\left(\left(I \otimes A\right) - \left(A^{\rm T} \otimes I\right)\right)\mbox{vec}(B) &= \lambda \mbox{vec}(B) \\
\end{align}

So, according to [Theorem 13.16](http://www.siam.org/books/textbooks/OT91sample.pdf), the eigenvalues of the Kronecker sum $\left(\left(I \otimes A\right) - \left(A^{\rm T} \otimes I\right)\right)$ would be $\lambda_i - \lambda_j$. Hence, the solution should be non-trivial if and only if $\lambda = \lambda_i - \lambda_j$.

Comment: This seems to be a valid reformulation. If you think about it a bit you will see that the proof of the theorem is not that different from the proof in the answer to the other question.

Comment: This is basically how Bourbaki proves it (Groupes et algebres de Lie, ch. VII par. 2 no. 2 exemple 3), so you should be good.